# Unable to fetch rendered dom using puppeteer

Tags: web-scraping, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I have recently been experimenting with using Puppeteer for fetching content from webpage and I have noticed that for certain webpages like https://www.scmp.com/news/china/diplomacy/article/3174562/china-needs-new-playbook-counter-eus-tougher-trade-and?module=lead_hero_story&pgtype=homepage, I am unable to fetch the actual dom that is rendered when the link is opened using a browser. The snippet I use to fetch the content is below:

```
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.scmp.com/news/china/diplomacy/article/3174562/china-needs-new-playbook-counter-eus-tougher-trade-and?module=lead_hero_story&pgtype=homepage', { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded', timeout: 60000 });
    const data = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('*').outerHTML);
    await fs.writeFile("./test.html", data, err => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err)
            return
        }
        //file written successfully
    });
    console.log(data);
    await browser.close();
})();
```

I already tried with a waitUntil value of `networkidl0` but could not extract the expected dom. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What are you trying to extract from the DOM specifically? Are you trying to save the whole HTML? If so, what purpose would this achieve?

Comment: @ggorlen Yes I am trying to save the whole HTML.

Comment: OK. Is there a reason not to use `page.content()`? I assume you want dynamic HTML rather than static HTML?

Comment: I tried that `page.content()` initially but that did not work.

Comment: Please elaborate on "did not work". What were you expecting and what actually happened?

Comment: @ggloren - I was expecting to see the same html that shows up in the chrome inspector after the page is fully loaded but that was not the case.

Comment: What was different, exactly? Please share a [mcve] and show exactly what HTML you expect, and what `page.content()` is giving you that's incorrect. According to [the docs](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagecontent), `page.content` "Gets the full HTML contents of the page, including the doctype" which sounds precisely like what you want. So if it's somehow not doing that, you'll need to elaborate on why with a clear example to reproduce the problem. There's not enough information here to diagnose the problem yet. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, `networkidl0` is a typo; that should be `networkidle0`. `domcontentloaded` doesn't wait for load events and external resources to resolve, which might be your problem. Is there a reason for using `document.querySelector("*")` rather than `document.documentElement` or `document.querySelector("html")`?

Comment: @ggloren - figured it out - I had to scroll the page in Puppeteer for the js to render the page as expected.